# No Audio in Risk of Rain

Tags: technical-issues, risk-of-rain

I installed Risk of Rain though Steam and everything was fine until a few days ago, but now I can hear neither sound nor music. Audio works fine in other applications, and I've checked the in-game settings and audio mixer.

The error log reports:

```
ERROR in
action number 5
of Create Event
for object oInit:

Error defining an external function.
```

### What I've tried

- Reinstalling the game
- Restarting Windows (Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit)
- Sacrificing 79 health at a life shrine
- Verifying the game cache
- The included FAQ recommends uninstalling and reinstalling Visual C++ in the `_CommonRedist` folder in the event of no audio. I've deleted the folder and allowed Steam to reacquire it.

Comment: Thank you @kalina for the `risk-of-rain` tag!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uninstall Redistributable 2008, 2010, and 2012. All of them. Restart your computer. Then go to your steam folder where Risk of Rain is. Then click on **_CommonRedist** folder then the **vcredist** folder. Install the files from the **2008** folder, the **2010** folder, and the **2012** folder. Some of the folders may be empty, but for the others, there should be **2** installers per folder. Run all of them. Restart your computer, this is necessary. Then try to run the game.

Comment: If you do the same for 2012, it works! I have an edit in the peer review process that'll update this answer to include 2012, but I'm accepting it now. Thank you!

Comment: I have no 2008 or 2010 folders.

Comment: I don't have them either, can you specify the required 2008 and 2010 versions?

Answer (score 3):

There's one potential solution that I've found which doesn't involve restarting your computer or messing around with C++ installations.

1. Exit Risk of Rain
2. Then close anything using Flash (ie: web browsers, other games, etc)
3. Restart Risk of Rain normally

For me, this issue manifested when I had some YouTube videos open in Google Chrome then started up Risk of Rain. Closing the specific tabs wasn't enough; I had to close Chrome itself before the sound worked properly.